# Grok Pattern to skip a character

Tags: logstash-grok

I have following grok pattern

%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:timestamp} %{SYSLOGHOST:hostname} %{LOGLEVEL:logLevel} %{SYSLOGPROG}: %{DATA:message_code:} %{GREEDYDATA:syslog_message}

Here is my message

"messages": "{"data":"<133>May  7 10:58:21 aa.bb.cc notice root[27119]: updatecheck[32172]: messagebody"}"

The question is for the "message_code" part, how can modify my grok pattern so it only parse "updatecheck" but ignore [32172]

Answer (score 0):

You can use he below grok pattern where I have taken the [32172] in different field.

```
%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:timestamp} %{SYSLOGHOST:hostname} %{LOGLEVEL:logLevel} %{SYSLOGPROG}: %{DATA:message_code}\[%{POSINT:random_number}\]: %{GREEDYDATA:syslog_message}\"}
```

**Output**

[image]

Now, you can ignore or drop the field **random_number** depending on your use case.

Comment: Thanks Sourav.  But i also want to be able to  use the same pattern to parse other  message_code which doesn include the random_number [32172].  For example 011e1004:3
Sorry i am new to Grok Pattern

Comment: It seems i can just add ()? to make it optional , like this , it works!
%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:timestamp} %{SYSLOGHOST:hostname} %{LOGLEVEL:logLevel} %{SYSLOGPROG}: %{DATA:message_code}(\[%{POSINT:random_number}\]:)? %{GREEDYDATA:syslog_message}"}